# Does linux use asychronous write for swapping when memory pressure is high?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I'm studying in Linux kernel swapping.

To my understanding, swap is performed by a demand thread and use asynchronous IO for dropping.

Does it mean that we need to wait for asynchronous IO when the memory pressure is high?

It sounds weird for me, so I'm not sure whether it always uses asynchronous write.

Comment: If a process needs memory and none is available there are only two choices:wait or kill the process.  Performance is only optimized for the normal case, not an out-of-memory condition.

Comment: Dose it mean we need appropriate swappiness to make sure out-of-memory would not become a normal case?

Comment: Swapping is fine, it is just not optimized for performance because with well-designed software it should be rare.  The swapping process is likely to be put to a wait state until the I/O completes.  Swappiness determines how often and how much.  For a server may be high (more throughput), for a desktop may be low (more responsive).

Comment: Besides, all writes in Linux are async, except by novice programmers who are still learning how I/O works.  Its almost always better to wait and batch multiple writes or avoid writes at all because the file gets deleted or overwritten.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree with you. There are so much reason to use sync write. (i.e. SQlite transaction, ext journaling, f2fs ckeckpoint) Also, the I/O scheduler would treat them in different priority. emmm..., anyway I found the answer I want and I put the reference [here](https://lwn.net/Articles/396561/)

Comment: Thanks. Its a good read.  The fix described was to reduce the sync reclaim writes and increase the priority of the background async writes.